# How to Add/remove 'prev' and 'next' classes to carousel slides in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to position the prev and next slides in a Bootstrap Carousel with CSS but the Bootstrap.js (version 3.1.1) seems to be only very briefly adding `prev` or `next` classes to adjacent slides before stripping them and adding the `active` class (depending on which way you swipe). In order to position the prev and next slides (and not the other slides in the sequence) I want to add the `next` class to the following slide and the 'prev' class to the prev slide relative to the current slide and keep them there until the slides change:

[Here is the example I'm basing it off](http://lazcreative.com/bs3/index.html), and here is the javascript that is used:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {  
     $("#myCarousel").swiperight(function() {  
          $(this).carousel('prev');  
            });  
       $("#myCarousel").swipeleft(function() {  
          $(this).carousel('next');  
   });  
});  
</script>
```

The correct behavior would be the following (note the movement of the `prev`, `active` and `next` classes:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="item active">
   Slide 1
 </div>
 <div class="item next">
   Slide 2
 </div>
 <div class="item">
   Slide 3
 </div>
 <div class="item">
   Slide 4
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Should become:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="item prev">
   Slide 1
 </div>
 <div class="item active">
   Slide 2
 </div>
 <div class="item next">
   Slide 3
 </div>
 <div class="item">
   Slide 4
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple jquery script to add the corresponding classes after each transition:

```
var $carousel = $('#myCarousel'),
    $carouselItems = $('.item', $carousel);

//This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.
$carousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    //Reset classes
    $carouselItems.removeClass('prev next');
    //Find current slide
    var $active = $(e.relatedTarget);
    //Add corresponding classes to next and prev elements
    $active.next().addClass('next');
    $active.prev().addClass('prev');
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/2nqddjpa/)**